# best practice for implementing pagination in spring reactive data mongodb

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, reactive

As far as I know, there's no support for pagination in reactive mongodb repository however you can still fetch chunks of data using `Pageable` or use `.skip` + `.limit` on `Flux`. But in the database itself, let's say mongodb, it still fetch the whole result and return it to the downstream because we didnt provide `offset` and `limit` to it which results in heavily db usage. So inorder to use this approach I may need to make sure that I don't have too big data in my table/collection.

So is there a way to implement true Pagination in reactive repository ? One ugly solution that I can think of is that to provide the order number as a field in the document and use it for paging like this.

```
@Document
class Person {
   private Integer numb;
}
```

and In my query using either `ReactiveQuerydslPredicateExecutor` or `ReactiveCrudRepository`

```
qPerson.numb.loe(specification.getPageSize());

personRepository.findByNumbLessThan(Integer pageSize);
```

but this approach wouldn't work when we need to comebine with other condtions to query.